# Laravel 4 : Controller with "_" underscore in the URL instead of "-" dashes

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

My route.php :

```
  Route::controller('ajax/project','Ajax_ProjectController');
```

I have Ajax/ProjectController as follows:

```
class Ajax_ProjectController extends BaseController {
 public function getTestMe(){
     echo "test";
     exit;
   }
 }
```

To assess this through the URL : /ajax/project/test-me , how can I make it access URL : /ajax/project/test_me ( Underscore instead ) is there away?

Thanks

Comment: What if you rename your controller method to getTest_me()?

Comment: And what about this before your above route: `Route::controller('ajax/project/test_me','Ajax_ProjectController@testMe');` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to do this without extending Laravels core is by manually defining it:

```
Route::get('ajax/project/test_me','Ajax_ProjectController@getTestMe');
Route::controller('ajax/project','Ajax_ProjectController');
```